# What is the difference between ‘만’, ‘뿐’, ‘밖에’?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning, particle

What is the difference in part of speech, meaning, and usage between ‘만’, ‘뿐’, and ‘밖에’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both '만' and '뿐' mean 'only', but I'd have to say I hear '만' a lot more. '뿐' also sounds slightly more negative in some contexts.

밖에 actually means 'apart from' or 'outside' is generally used with the verb '없다'.

Let's look at some examples:

*나는 파란색 만 있어. //
I only have the blue one.*

Notice the verb is '있다'.

*나는 파란색 밖에 없어. //
I don't have any apart from the blue one.*

The verb used here is '없다'.

*내 여름 휴가는 오직 1주일 뿐이야. / I only have a week of summer vacation.*

Here you can clearly see the speaker is *dissatisfied* with the amount of weeks that they have for their vacation.